# Jquery - Differentiate between 'click' and 'focus' on same input when using both

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, onfocus

I'm trying to trigger an event on an input if the input is clicked **or** if the input comes in to focus.

The issue i'm having is preventing the event from firing twice on the click as, obviously, clicking on the input also puts it in focus.  I've put a very loose version of this on jfiddle to show you what I mean, code as below:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input type="textbox" name="tb1" class="input1"></input>
    <label> box 1 </label>
    <input type="textbox" name="tb2" class="input2"></input>
    <label> box 2 </label>
</body>
```

JQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.input2').click(function() {
        alert("click");
    });
    $('.input2').focus(function() {
        alert("focus");
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/XALSn/2/

You'll see that when you tab to input2 you get one alert, but if you click you get two.  Ideally for my scenario, it needs to be one alert and ignore the other.  it also doesn't seem to actually focus.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Given that clicking gives focus, why do you need the click event?

Comment: It's to do with accessibility and how people use forms Utkanos.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobOwl Could you give an example where you still need click event?

Comment: Without going in to too much detail and boring you, it's all bout how users navigate websites/forms.  We take for granted that all users are at a certain 'skill level' or capability using a web page and so we're trying to gain some idea of whether people click or tab through websites/forms and how we can improve the journey of the website based on this feedback.  Hope that makes sense, it's not the most glamorous project but it's interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting a flag on focus so we can fire on focus and ignore clicks but then listen for clicks on the focussed element too? Make sense? Take a look at the [demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XALSn/12/) - If you focus or click on the unfocussed `.index2` it triggers the focus event and ignores the click. Whilst in focus, clicking on it will trigger the click.

**I have no idea why you would want this** (I cant imagine anyone wanting to click on a focussed element for any reason (because the carat is already active in the field) but here you go:

```
$(function () {
    $('.input2').on("click focus blur", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(e.type=="click"){
            if($(this).data("justfocussed")){
                $(this).data("justfocussed",false);
            } else {
                //I have been clicked on whilst in focus
                console.log("click");
            }
        } else if(e.type=="focus"){
            //I have been focussed on (either by clicking on whilst blurred or by tabbing to)
            console.log("focus");
            $(this).data("justfocussed",true);
        } else {
            //I no longer have focus
            console.log("blur");
            $(this).data("justfocussed",false);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XALSn/12/

Comment: This looks good Moob Thanks, There's definite differentiation here between the click and focus that can be manipulated.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

just add e.preventDefault() on the click event

```
$(function () {
    $('.input2').click(function(e) {
        console.log("click");
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.input2').focus(function() {
        console.log("focus");
    });
});
```

If I understand your question right, the e.prevnetDefault() will prevent the browser from automatically focusing on click. Then you can do something different with the click than would with the focus

Comment: I've not tested this on other browsers but in Chrome at least the focus happens before the click.

Comment: I didn't downvote you Gisheri, I did previously try this to no avail though.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be the best answer, but this is a way of doing it.  I would suggest adding tab indexes to your inputs and firing the focus event **when you blur** from another input.

I've added that to this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XALSn/9/

```
$(function () {
    $('.input2').click(function(e) {
    alert("click");
    e.preventDefault();
});
});

$('input').blur(function(){
    $('input').focus(function() {
        alert("focus");
    });
});
```

Comment: What if the user never clicks it? (Maybe they don't have a mouse) They'd have to tab in, out then back in to trigger the event for the first time.

Comment: @Moob well, on any form, as a UX standard, you should have a focus on the first field.  There should always be a focus. Especially so for accessibility sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one thing I am using very often in JS

```
var doSomething = true;

$(function () {
    $('.input2').click(function(e) {
        if (doSomething) {
        // do something :)
        }    
        doSomething = false;
    });
    $('.input2').focus(function() {
        if (doSomething) {
        // do something :)
        }
        doSomething = false;
    });
});
```

But You have to change value of doSomething on mouseout or foucs over etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var hasFocus = false;
    $("body")
    .off()
    .on({
        click : function()
        {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                hasFocus = true;
                alert("click");
            }
        },

        focus : function()
        {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                hasFocus = true;
                alert("focus");
            }
        }
    },".input2");
});
```

try setting a flag hasFocus and act accordingly

http://jsfiddle.net/AEVTQ/2/